# How to extract Name from a JSON Name/Value pair and append to a TextField

Tags: javascript, json, material-ui

I have JSON which looks like this:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Title": "Data about John Doe",
  "Comments": "Some text goes here",
  "UpdatedBy": "John Doe",
  "UpdateDate": "Apr 14 2022 12:00AM"
}
```

I want to map this JSON to MUI TextFields with the names of the name/value pairs as the TextField labels, and the values as the TextField values.  I also need to be able to edit the values.

This is my array of data:

```
const [singleSizing, setSingleSizing] = useState("");
const fetchSizingData = async (intake_id, sizing_id) => {
  setSingleSizing(
    await fetch(`/api/fiscalyears/FY2023/intakes/${params.id}/details/questions`).then((response) =>
                response.json()
            )
  );
};
```

These are the Text Fields I am using:

```
<TextField
  value={}
  label={}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `singleSizing` is one JSON object. If not, map over first:

You can use `Object.entries` to extract the key/value pair from the object and then `.map()` over the entries to create the components.

```js
// ...

  return Object.entries(singleSizing).map(sizingEntry => {
      const [label, value] = sizingEntry; // e.g. ['Title', 'Data about John Doe']
      
      return <TextField label={label} value={value} />
  });

// ...
```

To edit the values, look into a MUI form components or another form library and consider changing the shape of the state to make updates easier.

Comment: I have impletmented your solution but only the last line entry is being appended to a TextField: ``"UpdateDate": "Apr 14 2022 12:00AM"``

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map` & `Object.keys`

```js
 {
     
      
        Object.key(singleSizing).map(key => ( 
          <TextField 
              value = {
                obj[key]
              }
              label = {
                key
              }
            />
        ))
      
 }
```

Comment: I get the following error with this code ``Uncaught TypeError: singleSizing.map is not a function``

Comment: I Have updated the answer, to only render TextField when single-sizing is not undefined

Comment: Still the same error message.

Comment: Sorry I Made mistake now it would work

Comment: Now ``obj`` is not defined